# Android TextToSpeech behaves irregular

Tags: android, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

Update: After some digging I managed to find some information in the Logcat. See bottom.

Edit 2:
I have now created a new activity from scratch to reduce the problem. It does still not work correctly. Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextToSpeech textToSpeech;
    private boolean isInitialized = false;
    private MainActivity mainActivity;
    int ctr = 0;
    private String words[] = {"ord", "kula", "fotboll"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        mainActivity = this;

        textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){
                    textToSpeech.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
                            System.out.println("---onStart");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onDone(String utteranceId) {
                           System.out.println("-----onDone");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(String utteranceId) {
                            System.out.println("-----onError");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(String utteranceId, int errorCode){
                            onError(utteranceId);
                            System.out.println("Error with code: " + errorCode);
                        }
                    });
                    isInitialized = true;
                    Locale locale = new Locale("swe");
                    textToSpeech.setLanguage(locale);
                }
            }
        });
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (isInitialized){
                    System.out.println(textToSpeech.getLanguage().getDisplayLanguage());
                    textToSpeech.speak(words[ctr], TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, "SpeakTest");
                    ctr++;
                    ctr %= words.length;
                } else {
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Speaker not ready", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

What is extremely surprising is that only the words "ord" and "fotboll" are spoken, but not "kula". If I change `words` to `{"kula", "kula", "kula"}` and try long enough, it suddenly starts to work. As I have understood the documentation one should use the tags [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-2_codes). I have tried `se`, `swe`, `sv`, all with same result. Further, the command `System.out.println(textToSpeech.getLanguage().getDisplayLanguage());` gives `svenska` which is correct.

If I change to `en` it works all the time. Also I get `System.out.println(textToSpeech.getLanguage().getDisplayLanguage());
 = engelska` again correct.

What on earth is going on?

EDIT:

I have added a `UtteranceProgressListener`, according to [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/UtteranceProgressListener), the method

`onError(String id)` is deprecated and should be replaced by `onError(String id, int errorCode)`. However, I have extended my class with `UtteranceProgressListener` and it forces me to implement the old `onError` method. This is always called, so something is wrong but I do not know what.

This is because the other `onError(String id, int code)` is never called.

I have updated the code.

---

I have a function that is supposed to speak a word in a specific language when the function is called.

Until for a couple of days ago it worked fine in my Sony Compact XZ2, but now it is irregular. Sometimes the word is spoken and sometimes not. The command `textToSpeech.getEngines()` returns `com.google.android.tts`

For example for Swedish, in `setLanguage`, I have tried "sv" and "sv-SV" when I create the `Locale` object. That has not helped.

I just noticed that when I press the button that calls `playWord(text)` a bunch of times ( > 40) it works and sometimes it works directly. Seems to be some strange delay.

The function `speakText` is called from this function in my `Fragment`:

```
private void playWord(){
    if (text2Speech.isReady()) {
        text2Speech.checkSpeaking();
        text2Speech.setLanguage(getAcronym(mTraining.getCurrentSrc()));
        text2Speech.speakText(front);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Speaker not ready yet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

This is the class that handles the speaking. I have not obtained any error messages. It just seems random when the speaker works.

```
public class Text2Speech extends UtteranceProgressListener {
    private Context mContext;
    private TextToSpeech textToSpeech;
    private boolean isReady = false;
    public Text2Speech(Context context, final String src){
        mContext = context;
        System.out.println("text2Speech created");
        textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(mContext, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                    isReady = true;
                    Locale locale = new Locale(src);
                    int ttsLang = textToSpeech.setLanguage(locale);
                    if (ttsLang == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                            || ttsLang == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                        Log.e("TTS", "The Language is not supported!");
                    } else {
                        Log.i("TTS", "Language Supported.");
                    }
                    Log.i("TTS", "Initialization success.");
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "TTS Initialization failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean isReady(){
        return isReady;
    }
    public void checkSpeaking(){
        if (textToSpeech.isSpeaking()){
            textToSpeech.stop();
        }
    }

    public void showMessage(String msg){
        Toast.makeText(mContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    public void speakText(String text){
        int speechStatus = textToSpeech.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        switch (speechStatus){
            case TextToSpeech.ERROR_INVALID_REQUEST:
                showMessage("Invalid Request");
                break;
            case TextToSpeech.ERROR_NETWORK:
                showMessage("Network Error");
                break;
            case TextToSpeech.ERROR_NETWORK_TIMEOUT:
                showMessage("Network Timeout");
                break;
            case TextToSpeech.ERROR_NOT_INSTALLED_YET:
                showMessage("Error Not Yet Downloaded");
                break;
            case TextToSpeech.ERROR_OUTPUT:
                showMessage("Output Error");
                break;
            case TextToSpeech.ERROR_SERVICE:
                showMessage("Error of TTS service");
                break;
            case TextToSpeech.ERROR_SYNTHESIS:
                showMessage("Error synthesizing");
                break;
            case TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED:
                showMessage("Language nor supported");
                break;

        }
        if (speechStatus == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
            Log.e("TTS", "Error in converting Text to Speech!");
        }
        System.out.println("speech status - text " + speechStatus + " - " + text);
    }

    public void setLanguage(String src){
        Locale locale = new Locale(src);
        int tts = textToSpeech.setLanguage(locale);
        System.out.println(tts + "  " + src);
        if (tts == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                || tts == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Language not yet supported.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void stop(){
        textToSpeech.stop();
        textToSpeech.shutdown();
    }

@Override
public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
    Log.e("START", "start speaking");
}

@Override
public void onDone(String utteranceId) {
    Log.e("DONE", "done speaking");
}

@Override
public void onError(String utteranceID){
    Log.e("Error", "Not infromative");
}

// This is not called!
@Override
public void onError(String utteranceId, int errorCode) {
    Log.e("Error", "Error speaking");
}
}
```

Here is the error message in the Logcat:

```
NetworkSynthesizer: ExecutionException during NetworkFetchTask
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: clx: RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Quota exceeded for quota metric 's3-sessions' and limit 's3-session-limit' of service 'speechs3proto2-pa.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:529030122437'.
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:123)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:207)
        at avf.a(PG:37)
        at avf.a(PG:154)
        at com.google.android.tts.service.GoogleTTSService.onSynthesizeText(PG:250)
        at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeechService$SynthesisSpeechItem.playImpl(TextToSpeechService.java:1033)
        at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeechService$SpeechItem.play(TextToSpeechService.java:819)
        at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeechService$SynthHandler$1.run(TextToSpeechService.java:583)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:280)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
     Caused by: clx: RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Quota exceeded for quota metric 's3-sessions' and limit 's3-session-limit' of service 'speechs3proto2-pa.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:529030122437'.
        at cze.a(PG:58)
        at cze.a(PG:29)
        at dao.a(PG:21)
        at ave.a(PG:36)
        at ave.call(PG:80)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2019-03-16 21:35:46.917 1356-5238/? E/ActivityManager: Sending non-protected broadcast com.sonymobile.intent.action.POWER_BACK_OFF_FACTOR_CHANGED from system 2179:com.android.phone/1001 pkg com.android.phone
    java.lang.Throwable
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.checkBroadcastFromSystem(ActivityManagerService.java:21814)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:22423)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerService.java:22565)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact$broadcastIntent$(IActivityManager.java:10171)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:167)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3416)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731)
2019-03-16 21:35:46.917 12061-13318/? E/TTS.GoogleTTSServiceImp: Synthesis failure with error status code: -4
2019-03-16 21:35:46.918 12061-13318/? W/PlaybackSynthesisRequest: done() was called before start() call
2019-03-16 21:35:46.919 6468-6489/com.erikbylow.tailoreddictfire D/SPEECH: Error
```

When I turn WiFi on, it works.

Speculation: Can it be that the languages were missing and not downloaded when I did not use WiFi? When I turned WiFi on, the languages were downloaded?

To me this error: `clx: RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Quota exceeded for quota metric...` looks like there was always a network request, but after turning WiFi on, I could use TextToSpeach in flight mode.

On the other hand, I tried it woth russian in flight mode, that did not work. I turned internet on without WiFi, then it worked. Turned WiFi on again and then Russian worked as well. At least this suggests something needed to be downloaded?

I would like to find out what causes the problem and how to solve it since it is an app on Google Play. (Although I currently have exactly 0 active users beside me...) :).

Comment: I think you could track the problem down with log statements.

Comment: That is what I am trying to do with the UtteranceProgressListener, but that does not return any error codes, on my physical device.

Comment: Yes, but *something* is different between the situations where it works and when it doesn't.  You could also try building an extremely simple (as simple as humanly possible) project that speaks a word when you press a button.  You will probably find that it works fine... so then you know the problem exists somewhere in between.

Comment: Also... I don't think it's necessary to check isSpeaking because QUEUE_FLUSH will automatically interrupt and restart the speech in progress... that could be the issue.

Comment: Yes, I have done that and that seems to work fine. It would help if the `OnUtteranceListener` returned an error code.

Comment: The reason it doesn't return an error code is because whatever speech engine is on that Sony device was coded prior to the Android API where that method was introduced... they can't use a method that didn't exist yet... or they just decided not to use it.

Comment: It did not work fine when I reduced the problem and started a new activity.

Comment: Well if that is the case, then it would seem the problem is out of your control / not your fault.  You could post a new question with the reduced code, though.

Comment: I found some info in the logcat, when I turn WiFi on, it works perfectly.

Comment: Ah yes.. that's because the google tts engine does a lot of things in the background on the network, but tries to hide it.  So does this new finding mean your question is resolved? If not, you may find these answers helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573030/using-tts-on-android-punctuation-is-read-aloud, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50962724/how-to-predict-failure-of-google-text-to-speech, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51510129/android-text-to-speech-api-sounds-robotic

Comment: It works, but I have not changed anything. I have checked which TTS engine is loaded and that is always Google's. What does this "Quota exceeded for quota metric 's3-sessions' and limit 's3-session-limit" mean? Seems like a network request. I have tried in flight mode now and that also works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to give some closure: This was an Android Framework Bug that has been closed with Android 12 (API 31). See also my referenced Bug Ticket: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/138321382?pli=1